# Ember: Accessing many to many data from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm struggling to understand how to get the data from two related models to display.

I have a recipe that can have many tags and a tag that can have many recipes:

```
//models/recipe.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
});

//models/tag.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('recipe')
});
```

I am trying to do something like this from my recipes route (via a component):

```
//templates/components/list-recipes.hbs
<ul>
  {{#each recipes as |recipe|}}
    <li>{{recipe.name}} -  {{#each recipe.tags as |tag|}} {{tag}} {{/each}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

//templates/recipes.hbs
{{list-recipes recipes=model}}
```

If I output `{{ recipe.tags }}` I get a `<DS.PromiseManyArray>`.

How can I resolve this promise?

I tried adding `{include: tags}` to my recipes route - but it does not seem to make a difference:

```
//routes/recipes.js
export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('recipe', {include: 'tags'});
  }
});
```

My data:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the name when outputting your tag (i.e. `{{tag.name}}`)

Does this work for you? Everything else you have looks right ...

```
//templates/components/list-recipes.hbs
<ul>
  {{#each recipes as |recipe|}}
    {{! line below updated slightly }}
    <li>{{recipe.name}} -  {{#each recipe.tags as |tag|}} {{tag.name}} {{/each}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Also, for future debugging purposes, you can also use `{{debugger}}` or `{{log recipes}}` to track down what is going wrong

Comment: No, unfortunately that's not working either.  Also, if I output `recipe.tags.length` I'm getting 0, despite there being tags associated with the recipe.

Comment: Yes, that data info is helpful. It looks like your backend isn't sending the tag info as a standard JSON:API object, which would explain Ember Data's confusion. Specifically, your tags are *embedded* instead of *included*. To match the JSON:API spec you'd need to have a `relationships` key inside of each of your recipes that had information about what tags were linked to the recipe in question. If you take a look at the example on the home page here: http://jsonapi.org/ you need to match the `relationships.data` approach. Does that help?